# Open or closed set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this set

$A=\left\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

I need to show that it is neither open or closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

And that the union

$B=\left\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\cup\{0\}$

is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

My book has a Lemma:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $F\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if the following conditions is met:

For every convergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $X$ with $a_n\in F\;\forall n$ is

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\in F
\end{align*}

I know that $0$ is a limit point of $\frac{1}{n}$.

**$A$ is not open:**

Definition - Open:

A subset $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is open, if for every $x\in F$ there exists a $\varepsilon>0$, such that $F\supset(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$.

Idea 1:

For every $x=\frac{1}{n}\in F$ and every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an element $z\in\mathbb{R}\setminus F$ such that $x-\varepsilon<z<x+\varepsilon$.

Idea 2:

For $x=\frac{1}{1}=1\in F$ and every $\varepsilon>0$, is $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ not a subset of $F$.

Comment: $0 \notin A$ because $1/n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @TinPhan Thanks that was the argument I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @TinPhan can you please take a look at the ideas I've added to the question, on how to show that A is not open?

Comment: **Idea 1 :** No since it's in fact what you have to prove (but it's the idea). Notice that it doesn't prove that it's not closed (e.g. $A=\{1\}$). **Idea 2 :** You just proved that $1\notin \text{Int}(F)$... So it works to prove that $A$ not open, but it's not enough to proved that it's not closed. Moreover, even if it's obvious it would be a good thing to really prove that $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ is not a subset of $F$ (like to give an element of $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ that is not in $F$.  @dk20

Comment: @Surb Okay thanks! Yes I also found a way to show that $A$ is not closed, by the use of the Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is neither open nor closes since $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is a sequence of $A$ that doesn't converge in $A$.

$B$ is closed. Indeed, you can see that $$\mathbb R\backslash B=(-\infty, 0)\cup \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)\cup (1,+\infty )$$
which is open, and thus $B$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the last is just that $B^c$ is open right?

Comment: yes $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: can you take a look at my ideas on how to show that A is not open? I don't know which of mine ideas that are best. I've added it to the question.